# Why windows service not starting in sometimes AWS EC2 micro?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, service, windows-services

I have created a windows service exe from the python code, it starts when I start it manually in AWS Ec2 instances. Also Starts automatically some time when the ec2 boots up. But sometimes the service will not be stared in the instance, why is it happening some times. For your info I also increased the timeout to service start till 700000 in regedit key. still the service will not start automatically. Why is that happening? can I get some solution for this?

Comment: Try using this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2rescue-windows-troubleshoot/

Answer (score 1):

If the service is set to start automatically at boot but it isn't, there should be a [record describing the failure in the "System" area in the Event Viewer](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/event-viewer-troubleshoot-windows-services/#system-logs). Check those logs.

Also, try setting the service's "Startup type" to "Automatic (Delayed Start)". Doing so will delay service startup by a couple of minutes, which may be enough to fix the problem if it is a "race condition" as the system starts.